# How to indent the page number in the footer (memoir)?

Tags: header-footer, memoir, footer

I want to indent the page number on the foot, so it looks like in the image:

[image: Text]

As you can see, the position of \thepage is not aligned with the margin of the outer margin.

```
\documentclass[10pt,final]{memoir}
\setstocksize{20.5cm}{14cm}
\settrimmedsize{20.5cm}{14cm}{*}

\usepackage[layoutsize={14cm,20.5cm},textheight=16.5cm,textwidth=10cm,inner=1.5cm,outer=2.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,footskip=1.7cm,marginparwidth=1.5cm,ignorehead,showcrop=false,showframe=false]{geometry}
%,paperwidth=15.3cm,paperheight=21.3cm,layouthoffset=1.3cm,layoutvoffset=0.8cm
\usepackage{layout,lipsum,microtype}

\makepagestyle{headings}
\makeevenfoot{headings}{\indent\thepage}{\centering\slshape\leftmark}{}
\makeoddfoot{headings}{}{\centering\slshape\rightmark}{\thepage}
\makepsmarks{headings}{%
    \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
    \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
    \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
    \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
    \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
    \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
    \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
    \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}

\pagestyle{headings}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

This the MWE example that I´ve created. My intention is to indent the page numbers in both recto and verso pages.

I´d be very thankful if someone can give me a hand on this. Thank you,

**EDIT**

How can I align the numbers with the paragraph indent? As you can see, the number 1 is slighty outdented and I want it to be perfectily aligned with the par indent. Thank you again,
[image]![]

Comment: It works. Thank you @AlanMunn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the left edge of the page numbers on even number pages to line up with the `\parindent` it's best to change the overall width of the footer to be exactly the `\textwidth-2\parindent`.  We do this with the `\makerunningwidth` macro of `memoir`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,final]{memoir}
\usepackage{calc}
\setstocksize{20.5cm}{14cm}
\settrimmedsize{20.5cm}{14cm}{*}
\usepackage[layoutsize={14cm,20.5cm},textheight=16.5cm,textwidth=10cm,inner=1.5cm,outer=2.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,footskip=1.7cm,marginparwidth=1.5cm,ignorehead,showcrop=false,showframe=false]{geometry}
%,paperwidth=15.3cm,paperheight=21.3cm,layouthoffset=1.3cm,layoutvoffset=0.8cm
\usepackage{layout,lipsum,microtype}
\newlength{\myfootwidth}
\setlength{\myfootwidth}{\textwidth-2\parindent}


\makepagestyle{headings}
\makerunningwidth{headings}[\myfootwidth]{\textwidth}
\makeevenfoot{headings}{\thepage}{\centering\slshape\leftmark}{}
\makeoddfoot{headings}{}{\centering\slshape\rightmark}{\thepage}
\makepsmarks{headings}{%
    \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{\@chapapp\ }{. \ }
    \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
    \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
    \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
    \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
    \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
    \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
    \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}
\setcounter{page}{300}
\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\the\parindent
\chapter{Test}
\lipsum[1-15]
\end{document}
```

[image: partial output]

Comment: Hello Allan. Thank you very much. You´ve helped me so much. However, I have one more question. How can I align the numbers in the same position as the paragraph indent? Once the page number gets on three digits, it is not aligned. I´ve posted a screenshot on my main post. Again, thank you very much. I am still learning Latex :)

Comment: @RafaelBenítezMozos Do you want the numbers to be left aligned (so that a smaller page number still aligns with the parindent?)

Comment: I've changed the solution to something more robust for what you want.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly :)